Why is npx create-react-app not working even after the latest version of node and npm is installed?
I'm encountering this error everytime i try to create react app.

npx create-react-app .
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin
npm error path C:\Users\Desktop\projects\tictactoe
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin ENOENT
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent

I tried reinstalling node and npm, editing the system PATH variable but it still wont work. Also, when running npm config ls -l, the shell variable points to jdk which im unable to get rid of.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin - check whether any npm/npx bat file present on this path. also try cleaning npm cache using  npm cache clean --force.
